# Java printf: How define/declare empty spaces through a Conversion implicitly?

Tags: java, string, java-8, formatting, format

In Java having the following

```
printf("%-5s Hello %s %n", "", "There!")
```

It prints

```
     Hello There!
```

Where exists 5 empty spaces located to the left.

Until here it works how is expected, but ...

I want to know if is possible: How avoid the `""` declaration and change `%-5s` to something that `printf` can interpret that represents an empty space?

I mean: for example `%-5e` where **e** is assumed to represent an *empty* character and therefore is not necessary anymore declare `""` explicitly.

Something similar like `%n` where it does not required an argument through the `printf`. Is clear that `%s` requires an argument, in this case `""` but being curious if my request can be accomplished.

I read the [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadoc for that required feature and seems does not exist.

I already did do a research on SO and some suggested solutions is use the `+` within `printf`, but to be honest it reduces readability

Therefore the goal is (formatted for better presentation):

```
From: printf("%-5s Hello %s %n", "", "There!")
To:   printf("%-5e Hello %s %n",     "There!") // %-5e is the functionality I need or looking for
```

Comment: All you want is a way to print `5` spaces before `Hello There!`. How about `System.out.printf(" ".repeat(5) + " Hello %s %n", "There!");`?

Comment: Is possible do that without use `+`? I don't want lost readability

Comment: In fact, even my previous comment is not applicable in your case as you are using Java-8 (I just saw one of your comments). In order to make it easier for future visitors to this question, I've tagged it with `Java-8` now.

Comment: Is this really carrying the intended semantics? What about `printf("%11s %s %n", "Hello", "There!")`?

Comment: Your approach is totally valid, proceed to put it how the answer, to be marked by my side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 12 or higher and all you need is to adjusts the indentation of the resulting string, you could use `String#indent`. Using your example to insert 5 spaces at the beginning:

```
System.out.printf("Hello %s %n".indent(5),  "There!");
```

Since `indent` also normalizes line termination characters, you could also remove `%n`

```
System.out.printf("Hello %s ".indent(1),  "There!");
System.out.printf("Hello %s ".indent(2),  "There!");
System.out.printf("Hello %s ".indent(3),  "There!");
System.out.printf("Hello %s ".indent(4),  "There!");
```

to get something like:

```
 Hello There! 
  Hello There! 
   Hello There! 
    Hello There!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define new `printf` like this.

```
static Pattern EMPTY_CONVERSION = Pattern.compile("%-?(\\d+)e");

public static String printf(String format, Object... args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = EMPTY_CONVERSION.matcher(format);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(sb, " ".repeat(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return String.format(sb.toString(), args);
}
```

If you use Java 8, make your own `repeat`.

`e` is reserved for floating point conversions, so you might want to change it.

Comment: I understand, "e" was just a representation, could be any character ... "%anything"